# How do I customize the context menu in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus

From time to time I come up with ideas of actions I'd like to have available in the context menu of Nautilus. How do I add them there? Is there something like a Thunar UCA plugin for Nautilus?

Comment: for “Create new document” on right-click, refer this https://askubuntu.com/questions/777711/create-new-document-right-click-option-missing-in-ubuntu-gnome/791946#791946

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**This answer is outdated:** a recently updated answer is [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/77285/47206).

**App developers** wanting to add their app's actions — see this page below, [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/301205/9061) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/889974/9061).

---

Context menus of Nautilus used to be customizable by [Nautilus extensions](https://web.archive.org/web/20090322155517/http://live.gnome.org/Nautilus/Development/Extensions). Be warned that this link leads to archived doc; Gnome devs removed that documentation and no longer support that kind of customization. It may still work though.

You can also place plain shell scripts under the `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts` (`~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts` in early releases) directory, and they will appear in file context menu under *Scripts* submenu.

Comment: Please note that as said in http://askubuntu.com/questions/281062/how-to-get-nautilus-scripts-working-on-ubuntu-13-04 if you are on ubuntu 13.04 which uses a newer version of Nautilus, you are supposed to use `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts` folder to put your scripts in. And even then it will only show up scripts when you right click on a file or folder and not empty space.

Comment: isn't this outdated?

Comment: @cipricus it is. Answered on 2011, which is uh **6 years ago**. 12 Ubuntu releases earlier.

Comment: the question is not marked as edition specific and there are very recent answers

Comment: It's disconcerting to read:  *"devs removed that documentation and no longer support that kind of customization. It may still work though."*

Answer (score 38):

### Update for Ubuntu 18.04

At the date Ubuntu 18.04 was released Nautilus-Actions was/is no longer available. It also seems to have been superseded by a new program, called Filemanager-Actions, which otherwise looks identical.

---

To install this program, see [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1031746/47206) solution.

---

### Nautilus Actions

We may define our own right-click context menu items with [**nautilus-actions**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/nautilus-actions) [image: Install nautilus-actions].

- Run the *Nautilus-Actions Configuration Tool* either from the Dash, or from a terminal with

  ```
   nautilus-actions-config-tool
  ```

[image]

- In the *Action* tab give your action a sensible label, e.g. *"Open in Terminator"* and choose to display this in the selection or the context menu.
- Next open the *Command* tab to enter the commands to run

[image]

- Give in the full path to your command (`/usr/bin/command_to_run`) and program options.
- After **logging out and in** again the right click context menu below will be displayed:

[image]

---

Comment: Is this still up to date?

Comment: Nautilus Actions perform as expected in 12.04

Comment: Even without this tool, but following its logic: [Add a new Nautilus context menu action without `nautilus-actions-config-tool`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/353610/32012), and [Add 'Create launcher' to Nautilus context menu (without `gnome-desktop-item-edit`)](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/353580/32012)

Comment: Is `fma-config-tool` (see https://askubuntu.com/a/1138682/67132) the same tool under a new name?

Answer (score 13):

One can Use [python-nautilus](http://projects.gnome.org/nautilus-python/documentation/html/class-nautilus-python-menu-provider.html) extension as an alternative to `nautilus-actions`.

To install:

```
sudo apt-get install python-nautilus
```

A simple example:

```py
import os

from gi.repository import Nautilus, GObject

class ColumnExtension(GObject.GObject, Nautilus.MenuProvider):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def menu_activate_cb(self, menu, file):
         os.system("write here your simple bash command & pid=$!")

    def get_background_items(self, window, file):
        item = Nautilus.MenuItem(name='ExampleMenuProvider::Foo2', 
                                         label='Name of your item', 
                                         tip='',
                                         icon='')
        item.connect('activate', self.menu_activate_cb, file)
        return item,
```

Copy this python script under `~/.local/share/nautilus-python/extensions` and restart nautilus. When you right click on the desktop and select your item, your simple bash command will be executed :)

Comment: you may need to create `nautilus-python` and `extensions` folders if they are not there.

Comment: I tried most of the solutions in this topic and found that the python solution is the best one. Although not perfect, mainly because of lack of documentation, it allows for more flexible scripting and portability.

Comment: I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to 20.10. The package `python-nautilus` is not available on `apt`. Is there any ppa for this package?

Answer (score 6):

**November 29, 2016 era** Ubuntu 14.04, 16.04 and 16.10 plus earlier versions.

See Nautilus instructions for creating your own script here ([Help Ubuntu - Nautilus Scripts How to](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NautilusScriptsHowto)). Basically you:

- Navigate to the directory `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/`
- Place your script (written in Bash, Perl or Python) there.
- Mark the script as executable using Nautilus or from terminal with `chmod +x script_name`
- Nautilus makes environmental variables available to your script: `NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS`, `NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_URIS`, `NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI`, and `NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_WINDOW_GEOMETRY`

There are sample scripts located at ([Help Ubuntu - Nautilus Sample Scripts](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NautilusScriptsHowto/SampleScripts)) for e-mailing files, mounting an ISO file, setting files to read only, editing file with gedit ROOT priviledges, opening terminal at current location, etc.

Look through the scripts and take one as a template for encrypting files, uploading to the cloud, compressing to backup or whatever you need to do.

Comment: This still works in Ubuntu 21.04.

Comment: @ph0t0nix Thanks for the 21.04 update. Also thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 5):

## TL;DR

The best solution for app developers is to use [python-nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/a/301205/297110).

Create your python script ([following](https://projects-old.gnome.org/nautilus-python/documentation/html/nautilus-python-overview-example.html#id2684063) [examples](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Ecostales/folder-color/trunk/view/head:/nautilus-extension/folder-color.py) and bad [documentation](https://projects-old.gnome.org/nautilus-python/documentation/html/index.html)) and copy it to the correct folder:

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/nautilus-python/extensions && cp script.py ~/.local/share/nautilus-python/extensions
```

## Detailed Explanation

Let's say you want to create an application that the user installs with a script or a `.deb` file, with that in mind I'll be explaining why I think `python-nautilus` is a better solution compared with [nautilus-actions](https://askubuntu.com/a/77285/297110) and the [nautilus scripts](https://askubuntu.com/a/855198/297110).

### [Nautilus Actions](https://askubuntu.com/a/77285/297110)

This is the only solution to offer a GUI and therefore makes it easy to create complex behavior, for example decide what menu entries to show if the selected file's mime-type is `text/plain`.

The main problem with this solution is that it is not easy (if even possible) to import the entries to another computer without the Configuration Tool and the user importing it, let's just say it would not be possible to do with a script.

### [Nautilus Scripts](https://askubuntu.com/a/855198/297110)

This is the more straight forward solution, pick up a script, place it in a folder and done. This would definitely allow a install script or a `.deb` file to create a new entry in the context menu. What are the problems? Where do I start...

- It always appears under a Scripts sub-menu.
- It doesn't show if you have nothing selected.
- It doesn't allow you to decide if you should show the entry or not.
- Does not allow Tooltips or different Titles. (maybe I'm being picky)

A good app doesn't use shortcuts like this, because it ruins the user experience.

### [python-nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/a/301205/297110)

Not as easy to create as the previous solutions, but offers the best of both worlds. Scripting and customization.

This solution allows you to create a python script that receives the files selected in nautilus and let's you decide if you wish to show a entry or not and what to do with that entry. It also allows you to create sub-menus and or cool stuff.

The drawback is the big lack of documentation and developers that *just want to add an entry* may find themselves losing a couple of hours to create a working prototype (In my research I found a solution based on C that was way more complicated than this).

I normally use Visual Studio Code, while on Windows it offers a context menu entry `Open with Visual Studio Code`, it's lacking the same functionality on Linux, with the Python solution it would be easy to solve the problem. I think may apps in Linux could benefit from having a nautilus integration.

Hope this explanation helped you decide what to choose.

Comment: This is exactly the reason I wanted to add a context menu as well.  Could you perhaps post your "Open with VS Code" python-nautilus solution?  Thanks.

Comment: Cra0zy improved my version into a fitting solution: https://gist.github.com/cra0zy/f8ec780e16201f81ccd5234856546414

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be able to do something at any time, do like ulidtko says and use `~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts`.

If you want to be able to customize when you see it, install the nautilus-actions package, then go to System->Preferences->Nautilus Actions Configuration.