# Nautilus-compatible file "commander" for power users

Tags: gnome, nautilus

I was spoilt by Konqueror in KDE 3.5.x which used to:

1. integrated browsing of FTP,DAV,SSH,SAMBA resources
2. integrated terminals
3. powerful multi-pane and tabs support (it used to open web pages and other files)

---

I want to manage 4-8 directories at once, with the occasional SSH or Samba directory.

There are a lot of power-user file browsers, but I want something that plays **nice with the existing Nautilus** - with previews, bookmarks, context actions etc.

Comment: Maybe GNOME Commander?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. To browse the Network just open and mount a network location by *Bowse Network* or choose *Go -> Network*.
2. To have an integrated terminal see [Nautilus-Terminal](http://projects.flogisoft.com/nautilus-terminal/), also available from this [ppa](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983/3940): **ppa:flozz/flozz**
3. Nautilus 3 is able to open directories in a new tab by default (right-click context menu *Open in New Tab*)
4. For custom menus see [Nautilus Actions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21953/how-to-customize-the-context-menu-in-nautilus/77285#77285)