# "gconf-2.0 >= 2.8.0 not satisfied" error when installing nautilus action-3.1.5 from source

Tags: 11.10, nautilus-actions

I use ubuntu 11.10. I've tried to install **nautilus action-3.1.5** with the software centre. It's been installed but doesn't start at all.

Then i've tried to install nautilus action-3.1.5 from source but when i do

```
./configure --with-gtk=3 --with-default-io-provider=na-desktop --disable-gconf
```

there is a problem with gconf:

```
checking for GCONF... no

configure: error: GCONF: condition gconf-2.0 >= 2.8.0 not satisfied
```

The same error's signalled if i do the simple command `./configure` without paramethers.
What can i do?

Comment: See **note** from this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/77285/3940

Answer (score 2):

It will build fine on 11.10, you need to install [`libgconf2-dev`](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/libgconf2-dev)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug , just check the link 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/nautilus-actions/+bug/822282

**Solution**:

a fix for this, you must download the latest source from http://www.nautilus-actions.org/downloads/ and compile it with option --with-gtk=3 . It will work