# Nautilus scripts in top level of contextual menu

Tags: nautilus, directory, nautilus-script

Is it possible to have Nautilus scripts appear in the top level of Nautilus' contextual menu, rather than in a Scripts folder?

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 2):

Possible if you use Nautilus-Action. You may define your own right-click context menu items with this package. There is no need to store scripts in the `~/.gnome2/scripts` folder.Instead you can use the same script with `Nautilus-Actions-Configuration` Tool.

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-actions
```

[image]

### See the full answer here:

**[How to customize the context menu in Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21953/how-to-customize-the-context-menu-in-nautilus/77285#77285)**

---

Since most of the nautilus-scripts are basically Shell-scripts or Python-scripts (or Perl scripts) it is easy to convert them to nautilus-action scripts.

You can install most useful scripts from this ppa: **[ppa:dr3mro/nautilus-actions-extra](https://launchpad.net/~dr3mro/+archive/nautilus-actions-extra?field.series_filter=precise)**

Also you can fine many useful scripts here: **[Nautilus-action scripts](http://www.grumz.net/index.php?q=configlist)**