# How to get Nautilus-scripts working Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, nautilus-script, nautilus-extensions

How to get Nautilus-scripts (`Terminal here`, `Root Nautilus`, `Root Gedit`) working on Ubuntu 13.04?

I copied those scripts to `.gnome2/nautilus-scripts` folder but it dose not seem to work anymore

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try putting scripts in `/home/$USER/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/`

This is my scripts folder:

[image: Nautilus Scripts Folder]

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: That works but the script only comes up if I right click on a folder or a file and not on empty space in nautilus

Comment: I am not sure how to get right clicking empty space to open up the Nautilus script menu, but I think that would be another question. The folder used above does (I believe) work on right click of empty space in 12.10. I will confirm that soon, when I can get on a computer with 12.10.

Comment: your method works with nautilus 3.4 perfectly. The problem is only with nautilus 3.6. Anyways, temporary I am using Nemo file manager in which "open in terminal" and "open as root" are build in.

Comment: Ok! I think if you want more help with this though you should probably make a new question about right clicking in empty space with the new nautilus. As this question is about getting the scripts to work at all. I will try to look for an answer though

Answer (score 7):

### Nautilus Actions

We may define our own right-click context menu items with [**nautilus-actions**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/nautilus-actions) [image: Install nautilus-actions].

- Run the *Nautilus-Actions Configuration Tool* either from the Dash, or from a terminal with

  ```
   nautilus-actions-config-tool
  ```

With this tool I was able to make a context menu item to open terminal here. I've followed these steps:

[image]

[image]

[image]

One thing to note... It didn't show up on toolbar, or I didn't know where to look for it. So you don't have to check those two boxes in the second screenshot.

The whole thing works nicely, and I can click on files/folders or empty space to open terminal on *current* folder. It took a little effort to find out that the correct variable for folder path was `"%d/%w"`.

When I was in `/home/logan/games`:

- `%d` would get `/home/logan` if clicked on empty space
- `%d` would get `/home/logan/games` if clicked on any file/folder under games folder

But `%d/%w` seems to work for both empty space and on folder/file.

You may also need to logout and log back in, unless you restart nautilus to reload the context menu.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Nautilus-Action script to implement this.

Install gksu and nautilus-actions from the Software Centre
Then open the Nautilus-Action Configuration Tool

In the Nautilus-Action Configuration Tool create a new action
In the Action tab, type 'Open Folder As Root' in the Context label
In the Command tab, input the values '`gksu`' and '`nautilus %d/%w`' in Command Path and Parameters respectively.
Then Restart nautilus : `nautilus -q`