# How to associate a file extension to a non-GUI app in Ubuntu 18 Nautilus?

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, file-association

I'm using Ubuntu 18, and all the information I've found on web searches is outdated.

I have files with a .p4r extension that I want to associate to a non-GUI application.  These files are actually .zip files in disguise, but I don't want them to opened via the Archive Manager.

How do I get Nautilus (the file manager used in Ubuntu 18) to associate a .p4r file with a specific non-GUI app.  Because it's not a GUI app, it does not appear in the "Open With" dialog box.

Comment: The answer given in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1087166/how-do-i-persistently-change-default-file-program-associations-in-ubuntu-18-04 almost works.  It allows me to associate .p4r files with a shell script, but that only works in Nemo.  In Nautilus, the association is kept, but double-clicking on a .p4r file does nothing.

Comment: You should probably create a .desktop file for the non-gui application. Then, with right-click - properties, the non-gui's app desktop file will appear among the choices.

Comment: That almost works.  If I drag the .p4r file to the .desktop icon, it works.  But if I double-click on the .p4r file, nothing happens.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for that application, it may already have a way to do this. Also you might be able to make a link to the application in ~/.local/share/applications which may appear in the open with menu. See here for more info and more options: https://askubuntu.com/a/1073863/308524