# How to run a command through a keyboard shortcut in the current directory?

Tags: command-line, gnome, shortcut-keys

To open vscode I use `code .` in the directory I want to use. How can I assign a keyboard shortcut such that the command runs in the directory I am currently browsing? If it's not possible then how can I integrate vscode to my shell like in windows?

Comment: Currently browsing where?

Comment: @muru whatever directory I want to

Comment: Browsing with what?

Comment: You should clarify _where_. A shortcut when you are on a specific path while using gnome-terminal? You probably need an [alias](https://askubuntu.com/q/17536/349837)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to run this command via terminal. If so, the solution can vary a lot depending on what terminal you're using, if gnome-terminal, terminator, konsole, etc. Check the 'Preferences' menu of the terminal your using and search for Shortcuts or Keybindings, again it can vary a lot..

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using [nautilus scripts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281062/how-to-get-nautilus-scripts-working-nautilus). When you **install nautilus scripts**, a *Scripts* option will appear in your right-click menu. This menu contains all scripts stored under `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts`, allowing you to run them. These scripts run in the directory you are currently browsing, so you can just use your command, `code .`, as-is in your script.

This, however, still does not allow you to use a **hotkey**. To set that up, create a text file `~/.config/nautilus/scripts-accels`. You then can assign a hotkey, e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>, to your script adding the following line:

```
F11 VSCode
```

VSCode is the name of the script. If you use a different name, adapt accordingly. Remember names are case sensitive. You can also use spaces in the file name of the script, and then use that name literally in `scripts-accels` - no quotes or escape characters must be used.

You may need to log out and back in (or `killall nautilus`) before the hotkey is taken up.