# Filemanager-actions not available for Groovy

Tags: filemanager, nautilus-actions, nautilus-script, 20.10

I have been using `filemanager-actions` to implement some custom actions in my **Files** (Nautilus) application. I am a non-LTS Ubuntu user. I have used all the versions of Ubuntu since 18.10 on my main notebook computer.

Yesterday, I upgraded to 20.10 and `filemanager-actions` was removed automatically as part of the Ubuntu upgrade process. I searched today for a "*groovy*" version of this package, but there is none.

Does anybody have an idea of what happened to it? The only thing I have found on the Internet so far is this: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/filemanager-actions/+publishinghistory

I know about [Nautilus Scripts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281062/how-to-get-nautilus-scripts-working-nautilus), but is this *the* alternative intended for `filemanager-actions`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is another last nail to the GNOME coffin. There is no such packages [after 20.04 LTS release](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=filemanager-actions&searchon=names).

Simply use Caja with its [caja-actions-config-tool](https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/amd64/caja-actions/filelist) instead. Or the whole MATE desktop which is famous for its [flexibility](https://askubuntu.com/a/1263992/66509).