# Add "My App" to Context Menu in Ubuntu

Tags: context-menu, nautilus-actions

I have developed an app "MonitorMe" for Ubuntu.

In ubuntu I have seen now Microsoft has added Open With VS Code in Context menu without using Nautilus Action.

I want to add an option in context menu of Ubuntu like "Open with monitorme". How do do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application works on a certain type of file (a *MIME type*), you can write a .desktop file and associate your application with that MIME type; then it will be available in all file managers.

If you don't have any specific MIME type, you can cheat and use MIME type `inode/directory`, then you can open it from the context menu of directories.

#### Examples:

- [qdirstat.desktop](https://github.com/shundhammer/qdirstat/blob/master/src/qdirstat.desktop)

##### Minimalistic .desktop file

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=MyApplication
Exec=myapp %f
Icon=myapp
GenericName=MyApplication that does cool things
Terminal=false
MimeType=inode/directory;
```

Move that file to `/usr/share/applications` to make it available for all users on your machine. If you create a .deb package from your application to distribute it, install the .desktop file to `/usr/share/applications` in your `make install` step and package it with your application.

#### Further Reading

- Freedesktop.org: [XDG desktop file spec](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/)
- Arch Linux Wiki: [Desktop Entries](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/desktop_entries)
- Ubuntu Wiki: [How to add a MIME type](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddingMimeTypes)

Comment: Thanks it helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 20.04, you could still use nautilus actions, but in 21.04, this does not work anymore.

What still always worked are [Nautilus scripts](https://askubuntu.com/a/284331/558158). You put your script (with the executable bit set) in `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts`. They will then appear as a submenu of a "Scripts" right-click menu item. The [Ubuntu Community help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NautilusScriptsHowto) contains more information on how it works.