# how to call python script from Explorer right click

Tags: python, scripts, context-menu

I have written a tool in python which i want to be able to launch from the right click of the folder in the File and folder explorer... and I want to pass the folder i right click as argument to the python script !!

Comment: Are you using nautilus as your explorer?

Comment: yes, exactly.. why ?

Comment: You may be interested in [**python-nautilus**](http://askubuntu.com/questions/21953/how-to-customize-the-context-menu-in-nautilus) which will enable you to directly integrate your script using the nautilus python bindings.

Answer (score 3):

First check the version on Nautilus:

```
nautilus --version
```

- If 3.6 or above go to the folder: `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts`
- Else go to `~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts`

Now you should be able to just put a script in this folder. This works for bash (right click and there is an option called scripts), I think it works for python too. If the python script does not appear then you may have to make a bash script to call the python. Remember to make your script executable! Also [check out this link for more info](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NautilusScriptsHowto) (such as variables nautilus defines when your run scripts from right clicking, such as the folder or the file you clicked on).