# ubuntu rightclick command line custom backup

Tags: 12.04, unity, bash, backup, customization

os: `ubuntu 12.04 LTS`,
kernel: `3.8.0-35-generic` kernel,

when i right click on "text file/s",
i would like to have a custom menu, to run a bash, 
to make a backup copy of text file/s i'm right clicking on.

suppose i right click on the following three files:

```
/home/user_name/folder/file_1
/home/user_name/folder/file_2.c
/home/user_name/folder/file_3.sh
```

suppose time stamp is `2013/12/31 23:59:59`

i would like to have the following:

```
/home/user_name/folder/20131231_235959/file_1.bak
/home/user_name/folder/20131231_235959/file_2.c.bak
/home/user_name/folder/20131231_235959/file_3.sh.bak
```

how do i make this little toy? any help?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/21953/how-to-customize-the-context-menu-in-nautilus)

Comment: @Alex R. hi, how do i make menu appearing only on certain type of files, like for example only plain text files or only pdf files or whatever. ?

Answer (score 0):

You could easily achieve this using `Thunar` and its `Edit > Configure custom actions`. See [official documentation](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/custom-actions) on how to do this.

This said, I would advise against such setups. More efficient is to use an automatic backup and synchronization utility such as `SpiderOak`, which automatically backups the selected file and keeps a history of all historic changes. See [Comparison of backup tools](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools/20812#20812).