# How to add "open with custom command" option in right click menu of Nautilus

Tags: unity, command-line, gnome, nautilus

Sometimes while going to open a file from Nautilus I do not find the intended application in "open with" menu on right click. Or the desired application remains hidden in a long list of applications. It becomes difficult to find it quickly.

Prior to Ubuntu 11.04 there was a nice feature "Use a custom command" under "open with" menu on right click on a file. One could able write a command in the box to open a file with a custom application. This option is no longer available in Nautilus after Ubuntu 10.10.

[image]

**Question:**

> Can I have a similar "Use a custom command" dialogue box on Nautilus so that I can open a file writing any custom command in a box as shown in the above picture?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a small Nautilus script which gives you a "Use a custom command" dialogue box on Nautilus.

**The Script**

Save the following script as `Open with custom command` in the following directory

- `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/` (Ubuntu **13.04** or above)
- `~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts/` (Ubuntu 12.10 and below)

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
var=$(zenity --entry \
--title="Add Application" \
--text="Use a custom command" \
--width="320")
if [ $? -eq 0 ] && [ "$var" ]; then
    $var "$1"
else
    exit 0
fi
```

- Give the script **execution permission**. It is important, otherwise no change will take place. You can use in terminal,

```
chmod +x ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/Open\ with\ custom\ command
```

Or you can do it from GUI. Right click on the script, then go to **Properties** >> **Permissions** and check the box corresponds to **Execute** to give the script execution permission.

**How it looks like**

After that when you right click on a file you could see an option **Scripts** followed by another option under script **Open with custom command**.

[image]

When you select the option **Open with custom command**, you will get a dialogue box like,

[image]

You can write a command in the box to open the file.

**Usage**

You can open any file by entering corresponding application's command only in the dialogue box.

**For example** you can open a `.txt` file using `gedit` or a `.pdf` file writing `evince` in the dialogue box.

---

### Some Other Usage

**Open file as root:**

If you want to open a file as root, just use `gksudo` before your command. To open a `.txt` file as root you can use in the dialogue box,

```
gksudo gedit
```

**Opening an unknown file:**

If you are not sure which application to use to open an unknown file, you can use in the dialogue box,

```
xdg-open
```

**Opening a file with a Terminal Application:**

If you want to open a text file using `vi`, you can use in the dialogue box,

```
gnome-terminal -x vi
```

**Note:**

To use `gksudo` you need to have `gksu` installed. In Ubuntu 13.04 onwards it is not install by default. You can install it using,

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
```

Comment: This is nice. First I thought that this is a duplicate of [How to customize the context menu in Nautilus?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21953/147044), but not, this is more than that!

Comment: mmm, if I make that into a combo that shows previously opted commands, it may become really nice!