# Making Minecraft.jar executable

Tags: java, minecraft

So I've tried almost everything but when I click on the jar file it opens the archive manager. There is no option to run it with java.

Comment: Just a hint... java -jar "path to jar" + search for linux desktop shortcut...this way you will learn more, then if someone serves it to you on silver plate :)

Comment: @MichalHagara I know how to launch it from the terminal. Is there a way to launch it from just double clicking it?

Comment: you can make it open in java, right click-open with ...search for java sdk or whatever java you have installed....or create desktop entry with Exec=java -jar 'path to jar' or use bash script

Comment: @MichalHagara It won't let me use java runtime from the open with menu

Comment: In this case you should be able to use custom command...right click...open with...custom command...'java -jar' withou quotation marks...it should work

Comment: @MichalHagara Where's that? I only see open with application.

Comment: click on open with other application... it looks like this in my case http://tinypic.com/r/2mextau/8

Comment: @MichalHagara I did select open with other application. And I can't view your picture.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu Mate, but I suppose that another flavours has this function as well

Comment: @MichalHagara I am using ubuntu

Comment: please post picture of what you get when you click: open with other application... my image again: http://i.imgur.com/bbal1Ub.png?1

Comment: Nautilus doeasn't have this function by default from what I have understood http://askubuntu.com/questions/431703/how-to-add-open-with-custom-command-option-in-right-click-menu-of-nautilus, but it can be added

Comment: Or ubuntu tweak should be capable of file asociating http://popularubuntuquestions.com/add-custom-command-in-the-open-with-dialog/  other solutions are there as well

Answer (score 1):

Running jars in linux is easy. Just open a terminal and type `java -jar <path to jarfile>` then hit enter and voilà it works.

Comment: Like I said in above I want to be able to make a shortcut so I don't have to type it every time.

Comment: Then put that in a bash script and click that?

Comment: Oh okay. Can't believe I didn't think to do that. Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it works out. :P

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you tried to click on it, the location of the .jar file should be in the $PATH of minecraft. I don't have any experience mindcrafting, I have alot of experience programming in Java and administering Java dependant applications on Ubuntu; I also set my brother up with Gary's mod on Ubuntu 12.04.

So basically here's the diagnostic flowchart you want to follow when you are foo-bar:

1) Do you have a java virtual machine (JVM) installed (I used Oracle jdk7u26 I believe on that mod)? You can check by running the following command from command line:

```
:~$ java -version
```

2) Is the $PATH to the jre set ($JRE_HOME), either in your local startup script, the global startup script /etc/profile, or did your update the alternatives to give a symlink to /usr/bin/java, /usr/bin/jar? 
You can check by running the following commands:

```
:~$ echo $JRE_HOME

:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
```

3) Is the location of the .jar in the $PATH of the mincraft executable? 
In the possibility your using a mod.

4) Whats the permissions of the .jar file you want to run?

```
:~$ stat thisminecraft.jar
```

Also you have symlink for the jar and for java cause you updated /etc/alternatives, you can create a bash script, and add the script to a docking application like cairo-dock:

```
#! /bin/bash

RNJAR="java -jar /home/youruser/MyBin/theminecraft.jar"

$RNJAR

exit
```

So create a directory like:

```
:~$ mkdir -p -m0755 $HOME/MyBin
```

Then copy the script above into gedit and save as

```
/home/youruser/MyBin/minecraft.sh
```

Change the mode of access to executable

```
:~$ chmod +x $HOME/MyBin/minecraft.sh
```

And you can create a custom launcher on cairo-dock or even put the script in the $HOME/Desktop (<- I never do this) folder as opposed to $HOME/MyBin.

Good Luck, and may the minecrafting be prosperous.

Answer (score 0):

Java applications can have their own desktop or launcher icon to start like any other application.

To get there we just need to create a `minecraft.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications/` with the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Value=1.0
Type=Application
Name=MineCraft
GenericName=Minecraft
Comment=Start Minecraft
Icon=/home/<user>/.icons/minecraft.png ## choose any Icon you like
Exec=java -jar /full/path/to/minecraft.jar
Categories=Games
Path=/home/<user>/.minecraft/
```

Create or download any icon you like it to display and store it in `~/.icons`. The desktop file needs to have executable permission (right click *Properties*, *Permissions*, tick *Allow executing file as program*).