# When I open minecraft.jar it opens wine

Tags: wine, minecraft

When I try to open minecraft.jar it always opens using the wine program. What can I do to fix that? I've tried re-installing minecraft.jar. But that just 
re-opens the wine program.

Comment: please search a little in the future http://askubuntu.com/questions/636005/making-minecraft-jar-executable?noredirect=1#comment907804_636005, there are a lot of topics about minecraft on this site already

Comment: I have added my answer. If you need further clarification please comment. Please accept the answer if it is working.

Answer (score 2):

Open the Terminal .go to the file location using cd command and use the `java` command to run any `.jar` file:

```
java -jar minecraft.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run a .jar in a terminal like this

```
java -jar location/of/your/minecraft.jar
```

To make a file you can click to open, open Gedit and paste the following code (edited for your location) in to a new document, then save it where you like and name it `minecraft.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar location/of/your/minecraft.jar
```

Now right click `minecraft.sh` and choose properties and then the permissions tab and check the box `Execute`, now close this and double click `minecraft.sh` and Minecraft will run.

This is called a bash script and essentially allows running commands from a script (.sh) file, it is very easy to learn.

You can find documentation on bash scripting [HERE](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Beginners/BashScripting).

If you want to create a icon to click and add to the Unity launcher, you can make a .desktop like this.

Open Gedit and paste the following code into it and save as minecraft.desktop and now right click `minecraft.desktop` and choose properties and then the permissions tab and check the box `Execute`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=MineCraft
GenericName=Minecraft
Comment=Start Minecraft
Icon=/home/username/.icons/minecraft.png ## choose any Icon you like
Exec=java -jar /full/path/to/minecraft.jar
Categories=Games
```

As you can see this is more complicated, but we will go over it.

`Type=Application` - This is the type of program the file will execute.

`Name=MineCraft` - Name of the created executable

`GenericName=Minecraft` - Don't know how this differs from name (maybe someone can edit)

`Comment=Start Minecraft` - This is a comment on what the file will do

`Icon=/home/username/.icons//minecraft.png` - This is where you can put a picture of your choice to be the icon, it must go in your home/username/.icons

`Exec=java -jar /full/path/to/minecraft.jar` - Is the command the file will execute

`Categories=Games` - Is just the Category of the application

Some documentation for this is [HERE](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles)

This is a common issue with things like Minecraft that don't install or click to execute so this should cover peoples needs for executing and adding icons.

Answer (score 0):

Minecraft is available for linux users but the installation of the game is not as easy as it may seem. some distributions are not built ready for a graphic and java heavy game. here is a link to a tutorial on how to properly install minecraft on a linux system.

http://www.howtogeek.com/198476/how-to-install-minecraft-on-ubuntu-or-any-other-linux-distribution/