# I want to right click+ open terminal with custom terminals. HOW?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, gnome-terminal, guake

I'm okay with ubuntu's classic terminal, (I'm using 18.04) but I want something more useful if I can.

I installed guake, it works fine, except I can not open guake terminal in a specific directory. When I right click, I want to see 'Open Guake Here' or something, not just 'open terminal here'.

I also have installed a terminal called terminology, it is useful too, but still I can't open it in a specific directory.

Is there a ubuntu terminal that gives us this oppurtunity? Or can I add this option for my other little terminals?

Answer (score 1):

Run the following commands to add an entry called “Open Guake” to the “Scripts” submenu in Nautilus’ dropdown menu:

```bsh
echo \
'#!/bin/bash
cd "${NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI##file://}" &&
guake' \
>~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/"Open Guake"
```

to save the script,

```bsh
chmod +x ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/"Open Guake"
```

to make it executable and

```bsh
nautilus ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/
```

to visit the scripts directory for the script to appear in the dropdown menu. When you click the new “Open Guake” entry now, Guake opens up with the current directory as your `PWD`.

#### Further reading

- [How can I add a custom item to the nautilus context menu, but NOT in a sub-menu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/215370/507051)
- [Nautilus Scripts Howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NautilusScriptsHowto)
- [Nautilus Script with `zenity` dialogue](https://askubuntu.com/a/431704/507051)
- [Nautilus File Manager Scripts](http://g-scripts.sourceforge.net/index.php)
- [(possibly outdated) Example Scripts](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NautilusScriptsHowto/SampleScripts)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But I get an error after I run `nautilus ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/`, then I get:  `/home/teoman/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/Open Guake: line 2: cd: file:///home/teoman/.local/share/nautilus/scripts: No such file or directory`

Comment: @TeomanYüksel I updated the answer, try again by simply running all three commands please.

Comment: Haha thanks for the occupation, but I get `Nautilus-Share-Message: 19:53:59.566: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process “net” (No such file or directory)
` at the end.

Comment: @TeomanYüksel `net usershare info` is something else entirely.  What did you do to get that error?  Trying to share something from Nautilus?

Comment: @Fabby Just followed the dessert's instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Running Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. Full credit to  [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152193/how-to-open-directory-in-guake-from-nautilus) solution. I'm posting here to fully elaborate on the process which worked for me:

1. Navigate to the location where scripts are stored for nautilus:

   ```
   cp ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/
   ```
2. Then create a new file for the script in your text editor of choice (you might like to call it "Open in Guake")

   ```
   sudo nano "Open in Guake"
   ```
3. Add the following code to the file:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   base="`echo $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI | cut -d'/' -f3- | sed 's/%20/ /g'`"
   if [ -z "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS" ]; then
    dir="$base"
   else
        while [ ! -z "$1" -a ! -d "$base/$1" ]; do shift; done
        dir="$base/$1"
   fi

   guake -n "$dir" -r "`echo ${dir%/} | rev | cut -d'/' -f1 | rev`" -t
   ```
4. Save the file, and change the permissions to make it executable

   ```
   sudo chmod +x "Open in Guake"
   ```

Fingers crossed, you should now be able to **click on a file or folder**, and a scripts menu should now appear, with a sub-option to open the directory of that file/folder in Guake. I didn't need to reboot or restart Nautilus to get it going.

**NOTE: You can't click in white space for this to work** (I wasn't able to find a solution to this). The scripts menu is hard-coded to work only when right-clicking on files/folders.

Also, if Guake is not open, it probably won't pop up either. However, if you hit <kbd>F12</kbd> or your defined mapping to open Guake, it should open to the tab with the folder.