# How to enable file creation from nautilus right-click menu on Gnome?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, menu, customization

I have got Ubuntu Gnome 15.04, with Gnome Shell, and Gnome 3.14, and I have noticed that unlike with Unity, Nautilus does not have the option to create different files with a right-click, just the ability to create a new folder. How can I add this option?

---

**OS Information:**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
```

**Package Information:**

```
nautilus:
  Installed: 1:3.14.2-0ubuntu9.1
  Candidate: 1:3.14.2-0ubuntu9.1
  Version table:
 *** 1:3.14.2-0ubuntu9.1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:3.14.2-0ubuntu9 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: refer this http://askubuntu.com/questions/21953/how-do-i-customize-the-context-menu-in-nautilus

Comment: refer this also https://askubuntu.com/questions/777711/create-new-document-right-click-option-missing-in-ubuntu-gnome/791946#791946

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Create a new (empty) file with the file type of your choice in `~/Templates`, eg a simple (txt) file:

```
touch ~/Templates/empty.txt
```

After that you can create a new file with a right click in Nautilus.

---

*Example screenshot*

[image]

Comment: Did you meant "file type"?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel `file type`?

Comment: On your first line, you have `"Create a new (empty) file with the fily type of your choice[...]"` (notice the `fily type`).

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel ah, ok =), you could make the correction and get 2 points ;)

Comment: It doesn't let me do 1-char edits with such low reputation.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel ah sorry, I forgot.

Comment: Don't worry. You got my upvote anyway.

Comment: Didn't work for me Ubuntu 16.10 and that sucks.

Comment: worked for me on Ubuntu 17.04 - the name of the "Templates" folder may be localized (it's "Vorlagen" in german). Check `XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR` in `.config/user-dirs.dirs`