# How do I enable 'New Document' option without pre-set name?

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, text, document, templates

When you right-click on an empty space, there's the option to create a new folder. Old versions of Ubuntu used to include the option to create a new text document as well, but now you need to enable this manually by creating a file in `~/Templates`.

However, this way the document will always have a pre-set name, so that you need to right-click it again and rename it.

Is it possible to restore the original way it was, i.e. you chose the name just after you clicked "New Document", exactly like the "New Folder" button?

[image]

Comment: The name was always preset, i.e Untitled Document.  What you're seeing has nothing to do with that. The current nautilus doesn't create the file with focus in the filename area. So to get the old behavior use a different file manager.. (- you'd see the same (poor) behavior with Create New Folder

Comment: Press F2 while the new file is selected and you will give it any name you want. Indeed, it has always worked this way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a new document and rename it directly (in one step) in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032017/create-a-new-document-and-rename-it-directly-in-one-step-in-ubuntu-18-04) (not very elegant answers)

Comment: @vanadium It's not completely correct to say *it has always worked this way*, previously there was no need for <F2>. This is from my Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 installation: https://i.imgur.com/iNOcpWU.mp4

Comment: @pomsky: I see: the rename box then was automatically opened after creating the new file in previous versions. Removed apparently as nautilus moved to the rename dialog rather than the in-field rename editing box. I did not miss this, although I also use the feature regularly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to create a simple txt file without opening the terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917502/is-there-any-way-to-create-a-simple-txt-file-without-opening-the-terminal)