# How can I open a folder in Atom editor directly from within my file manager's context menu?

Tags: nautilus, nautilus-actions, atom

**Is it possible to extend the context menu as follows?**

[image]

Comment: Isn't Atom a text editor? What would it do with a folder? ...seems related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/21953/how-do-i-customize-the-context-menu-in-nautilus

Comment: Atom has many features which include an environment.  It also has a folder pane.  Features includes text searches in the folders and package management.

Comment: See https://discuss.atom.io/t/no-open-with-atom-context-menu-entry-with-nautilus/35120, you can add it manually: https://askubuntu.com/questions/21953/how-do-i-customize-the-context-menu-in-nautilus#77285

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it as long as you are in the parent folder, not in the folder itself I guess.

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer! Do you want to add [this](http://i.imgur.com/JiAhrLf.png) screenshot to your answer?

Comment: Done, glad it helped :)

Comment: In Windows you could do this without any customization, on Linux customization is needed, but default is the way on the screenshot which is also not bad

Comment: Actually I do not see any "Open With" menu on folders.

Comment: At least in Gnome 3.20.4, you **can** configure Gnome Files (nee Nautilus) to run Atom against the current folder. 
In the screenshot below, I'm using the Nautilus-Actions Configuration Tool (nautilus-actions package): ![text](https://i.imgur.com/UdBad6H.png)

Comment: This worked in Nemo too (default file explorer for Linux Mint). When you click on "Open With >", go to "Other Applications", click Atom, and then click "Add To List". Then when you click on "Open With >", Atom will show up.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the Custom Action in the Edit menu! [image]
Press the big green plush sign to ad another custom menu entry!
This brings up another selector!
[image]
Fill this in, and make relevant selections from next tab, try it out a few times to get it right!
Thats it, you are good to go!

Comment: Is this Nautilus file manager?

Comment: Ubs actually no it is Thunar, but most of them have similar features - when it is usefull it pops up in the others as well.