# What does Ununtu 17.10 invoke when I use "Extract here"?

Tags: nautilus, 17.10, extract, unzip

I am using Ubuntu 17.10, with Unity. I have a zip file, which, when unzipped with "Extract here", produces error

> There was an error while extracting "file.zip". Error opening file "/path/to/file/subdirectory": Not a directory.

Anyway, when I use `unzip` from command line - the operation is successful. When I use Archive Manager, it is also successful. I wonder what program "Extract here" invokes. And how can I check for other context menu items what is invoked? 
Also, any clues what might be the cause for this behavior are very welcome.

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://askubuntu.com/questions/21953/how-do-i-customize-the-context-menu-in-nautilus/77285#77285