In Nautilus, is there a way to make the 'Set as Background' button call a bash script?
Nautilus doesn't have this as a setting. When setting an image as background i get the error
Failed to set wallpaper via portal: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface “org.freedesktop.portal.Wallpaper” on object at path /org/freedesktop/portal/desktop.
I also have a bash script which can set wallpapers and am using hyprland.

Most likely a bug, I don't feel comfortable in closing this as a duplicate of the actual question you have (request for a workaround) as maybe there's an easy fix to this, however you want this (use the "manual" method of placing the script in the appropriate location, I've succesfully done the same recently): https://askubuntu.com/a/21956/380067

Please add version information. I cannot reproduce on 22.04. Also make clear what you mean by "Nautilus doesn't have this as a setting.". No, you cannot replace internal nautilus commands by custom scripts. You can use the poorly documented Nautilus scripts, though.
